# Do SSRS subscriptions attempt to run their reports again in the event of a failure? eg. deadlock, timeout, etc

Tags: reporting-services

I ask because one of my scheduled reports failed due to a SQL error, which I quickly fixed, and then the subscription produced a result. However the subscription time had already passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, report are not automatically run.

I use AddEvent in the Report Server db on the Report Server to rerun a subscription. It works with either e-mail or file share.

```
EXEC dbo.AddEvent @EventType = 'TimedSubscription', @EventData =  '4511b87e-0fc0-486a-a472-c36bccaaa2b4'
```

The **Event Data** is the **Subscription ID** from the report's subscription. You can right click on edit and get the ID from the shortcut.

[image]

**Subscription Shortcut:**

> http://sql01/Reports/Pages/SubscriptionProperties.aspx?ItemPath=%2fDepartments%%2fReporting%2fCensus&IsDataDriven=False&**SubscriptionID=14ba4435-de95-4134-baaa-442676bcd54c**&RedirectUrl=http%3a%2f%2fkhsdasql01%2fReports%2fPages%2fReport.aspx%3fItemPath%3d%252fDepartments%252f%2bCensus%26SelectedTabId%3dPropertiesTab%26ViewMode%3dList%26SelectedSubTabId%3dSubscriptionsTab

You could probably build something to identify the failures and re-run all jobs that failed at a certain time. That would be a bit of work for something that shouldn't happen that often. If you do, post it for others.

Answer (score 0):

I am using following query to get corresponding SQL Jobs scripts and running them manually as required

```
USE ReportServer 
GO


CREATE TABLE #tempReports(LogEntryId BIGINT, subscriptionid VARCHAR(1000),LastRunTime DATETIME,  _Description VARCHAR(1000), ReportID VARCHAR(1000), 
             LastStatus VARCHAR(1000), rowNum INT)
INSERT INTO #tempReports
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT E.LogEntryId, S.subscriptionid, LastRunTime,  S.Description, E.ReportID, S.LastStatus,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY E.ReportID, S.Description ORDER BY S.LastRunTime DESC) as rowNum
    FROM [ExecutionLogStorage]  E
    INNER JOIN Subscriptions S
        ON S.Report_OID = E.ReportID 
    WHERE 1 = 1
    AND (
        S.LastStatus LIKE '%has been saved to the "\\<server>\c$\SSRS_Report_Export\20%'
        )
)T
WHERE rowNum = 1
ORDER BY ReportID, Description


CREATE TABLE #ExecutionStatements (ExecStatement VARCHAR(1000), job_name VARCHAR(1000), theReportOrder INT,
            LogEntryId BIGINT, subscriptionid VARCHAR(1000), LastRunTime DATETIME,  _Description VARCHAR(1000), 
            ReportID VARCHAR(1000),  LastStatus VARCHAR(1000))
INSERT INTO #ExecutionStatements
SELECT 'exec sp_start_job @job_name = ''' + cast(j.name as varchar(40)) + '''' AS ExecStatement,
        j.name AS job_name, 
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER(ORDER BY LogEntryId) AS theReportOrder,
        LogEntryId, subscriptionid,LastRunTime,  _Description, ReportID, 
        LastStatus
from msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
join msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js 
    on js.job_id = j.job_id        
join #tempReports s 
    on js.command like '%' + cast(s.subscriptionid as varchar(40)) + '%'
WHERE 1 = 1

---Execute required statements in MSDB
SELECT E.ExecStatement + '--'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),E.theReportOrder), E.theReportOrder, *
FROM #ExecutionStatements E
--WHERE subscriptionid = '3AFDAC30-4F30-423F-9F72-7C04C86026AB'
ORDER BY E.theReportOrder

SELECT DISTINCT S.subscriptionid, S.Description, E.ReportID, S.LastStatus, MAX(LastRunTime)    -- 2021-04-25 18:35:00.840
FROM [ExecutionLogStorage]  E
INNER JOIN Subscriptions S
    ON S.Report_OID = E.ReportID 
WHERE S.subscriptionid = '3AFDAC30-4F30-423F-9F72-7C04C86026AB'
GROUP BY S.subscriptionid, S.Description, E.ReportID, S.LastStatus
```